# Triggering CSS3 animation on jquery .show()

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a nice little three-part iPhone-esque "pop" animation prepared for use with a "too long" error to present to the user. To use it, I just call .show() on the hidden error div. Under Safari it works beautifully, but under Firefox it just lands with a thud, skipping the animation entirely and just doing a regular old .show().

What can I do to get this to work under mozilla too?

The relevant CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pop-in {
    0% { opacity: 0;-moz-transform: scale(0);-webkit-transform: scale(0); }
    50% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1.5);-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
    100% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1);-webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-moz-keyframes pop-in {
    0% { opacity: 0;-moz-transform: scale(0);-webkit-transform: scale(0); }
    50% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1.5);-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
    100% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1);-webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-ms-keyframes pop-in {
    0% { opacity: 0;-moz-transform: scale(0);-webkit-transform: scale(0); }
    50% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1.5);-webkit-transform: scale(1.5); }
    100% { opacity: 1;-moz-transform: scale(1);-webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes pop-in {
    0% { opacity: 0;transform: scale(0);transform: scale(0); }
    50% { opacity: 1;transform: scale(1.5);transform: scale(1.5); }
    100% { opacity: 1;transform: scale(1);transform: scale(1); }
}


#error {
    ...
    -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.3s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.3s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.3s;
    animation:pop-in 0.3s;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829032/css-animation-pausing-when-element-is-hidden . Basically, you put the CSS animation in a separate class that you add and remove as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your selector to #error.active and after showing the element, add the .active class..

Comment: Works quite well and is very simple! Hard to believe I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jquery.show() has a default duration of 400.

Use jquery.show(0);
then animate your element with css opacity via $("#idElement").addClass("myOpacityClass");